# Restore data-only postesql dump?

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I've got a postgresql question.

I'm somewhat new to postgresql, so please bear with me.

I'm working to restore a provided postgres data-only-dump, in plain-text format. The pg_dump was created with the following syntax:

```
$> pg_dump -a -h*** -U *** -T *** -T**** -T*** > outfile.sql
```

Is there anyway to load this into a brand-new database, without knowing the layout/schema of the database?

From what was explained to me, the data-only-dump was needed in order to maintain confidentiality of our db-schema. The data-dump was requested of one of our clients, and they need to retrieve the data from said pg_dump.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

the simplest here looks mocking up structure without strict data types. You can try casting `COPY` statement to `CREATE TABLE`, E.g:

```
MacBook-Air:~ vao$ pg_dump -d db -t person -a | grep COPY
COPY person (login_name, display_name, abstract, ts_abstract) FROM stdin;
```

so you add couple of seds:

```
MacBook-Air:~ vao$ pg_dump -d db -t person -a | grep COPY | sed 's#COPY#CREATE TABLE#g' | sed 's#,# text,#g' | sed 's#)# text)#g' | sed 's# FROM stdin##g'
CREATE TABLE person (login_name text, display_name text, abstract text, ts_abstract text);
```

Further you can use your dump as is and then try guessing the mysterious confidential db-schema...